# get "file:///storage" path from MediaType.ALLMEDIA in cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I need to upload all type of files in my application and for images I need to get image height and width and for that I am using:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(){
        $scope.imageUploading = true;
         var options = {
            quality: 70,
            //~ targetWidth: 1005,
            //~ targetHeight: 693,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
            mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
            correctOrientation: true
        };
      $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
         imageData = imageData.split('?');
         var imageURI = imageData[0];
         // This function is called once an imageURI is rerturned from PhoneGap's camera or gallery function
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, function(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.file(function(fileObject){
                // Create a reader to read the file
                var reader = new FileReader();
                // Create a function to process the file once it's read
                reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                    // Create an image element that we will load the data into
                    var image = new Image()
                    image.onload = function(evt) {
                        // The image has been loaded and the data is ready
                        var image_width = this.width
                        var image_height = this.height
                        if(parseInt(image_width) < confArr.image_sizes.portfolio.large.w || parseInt(image_height) < confArr.image_sizes.portfolio.large.h){
                            Auth.toastMessage($rootScope.appMainLang.formvalidation.upload_resolution_limit.replace('%s',parseInt(confArr.image_sizes.portfolio.large.w)),'long','center');
                            $scope.imageUploading = false;
                            $ionicLoading.hide();
                        }else{
                            $scope.imageUploading = true;
                            $scope.jrCrop(imageURI);
                        }
                        image = null
                    }
                    // Load the read data into the image source. It's base64 data
                    image.src = evt.target.result
                }
                // Read from disk the data as base64
                reader.readAsDataURL(fileObject)
            }, function(){
                Auth.toastMessage("There was an error reading or processing this file.","long", "center");
            })
        })


       }, function(err) {
           $scope.imageUploading = false;
           $ionicLoading.hide();
        // Auth.toastMessage(Auth.getlocal("timeoutText","string"),"long", "center");
      });
    }
```

when I use 
    mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,

in above code it returns path of file as "file:///storage/emulated/0/...." and is working correctly.
but as I need to upload all types of files so I replaced above line with

```
mediaType: Camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA
```

and with this path of file becomes "/storage/emulated/0/..." and then it do not enters in "window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL" function.
So is there a way to convert this later path to above mentioned like path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the file:// to the string. Like this:

```
var imageURI = 'file://' + imageData[0];
```

Comment: this is the path which I am getting using "mediaType: Camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA"  - /storage/emulated/0/download/unnamed.png. ANd using "mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE" path is  -  file ///storage/emulated/0/android/data/com.myapp/cache/unnamed.png

Comment: So when you use Camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA just use my answer to append file:// to the path.

Comment: but paths of those two are different, appending  file:// will not work, please notice the file paths.

Comment: The reason it works is because it is the same file but when you use PICTURE the camera plugin gives you the file in your apps cache then it's up to you to save the file if you edit it. When Using ALLMEDIA the plugin actually returns the direct file.